# Getting highest value from a table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class tst(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Price = models.FloatField()
    Perc = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(tst, self).save()
```

From a view, i would like to get the highest value for the column`Perc` and the name of `Item` for that value. How can i do that?

I tried to use aggregate:

```
max = tst.objects.aggregate(Max('Perc'))
```

But other than returning `None`, it doesn't return the value `Item` for the row with the highest `Perc`. Is there any way to do that in django? Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [sort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) queryset by `Perc` and get first element:

```
tst.objects.order_by("-Perc").first().item
```

Comment: Just one more thing, printing this variable will give me only the name. To get also the number value, am i supposed to do another query?

Comment: @Jack022 no you don't need another query. You can assign result of query to some variable: `result = tst.objects.order_by("-Perc").first()`. Now as `result` you will have full object. And you can do `result.item` or `result.Perc` or `result.Price`.